# How to implement loading directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement loading sniper... But problem is when I put sniper inside html it not working. here is my direcitve:

```
angular.module('commentsApp', [])
        .directive('loading', loading);


function loading($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
        {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
            {
                if (v) {
                    elm.show();
                } else {
                    elm.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="loading-spiner-holder" data-loading ><div class="loading-spiner"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" /></div></div>
```

In my commentsController I added like this:

```
angular.module('commentsApp')
        .controller('CommentsCtrl',function(loading){
```

Anyone know what is problem?

Comment: Could please add a Plunkr? Ideally with a button "create xhr request".

Comment: The first issue I see is that your directive is called loading, but in html you call it `data-loading`.

Comment: I also tried with just `loading` but don't work.

Comment: what do u need the loader for? Is it gonna be dynamically used for promises? or just render while loading images?

Comment: I need to wait till finish all `$http GET` requests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mycdf6v/3/). Your problem is maybe just because [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) does not have functions `show` and `hide`.

```
scope.isLoading = function () {
    scope.remained = $http.pendingRequests.length;
    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
};
scope.iAmLoading = scope.isLoading();

scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v) {
    scope.iAmLoading = v;
    if (!v) console.log('All loaded');
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-show="iAmLoading" loading>Loading ({{ remained }} remainded) ...</div>
```